# Python read a xml 1 -M and create json

Tags: python, json, xml

i have develop a python script taht read a tag of xml file and after convert the result into json.
Now the problem is that the xml for each one element have some tag (relation 1 - M)

```
<idpoint>1021</idpoint>
<tipopoint>1</tipopoint>
<latitude>45.188377380</latitude>
<longitude>8.612257004</longitude>
<previsione time="2015-07-11T12:00:00">
<id_tempo>1</id_tempo>
<desc_tempo>sereno</desc_tempo>
<symbol_day>1</symbol_day>
<temp>33</temp>
</previsione>
<previsione time="2015-07-11T18:00:00">
<id_tempo>1</id_tempo>
<desc_tempo>sereno</desc_tempo>
<symbol_day>1</symbol_day>
<temp>29</temp>
</previsione>
```

My code python read the first tag and when i arrive to tag previsione that is repeat 2 time for the same point i take the first value of first tag previsioni but doesn't take the second.
I could recreate a same record but this time take the value of second tag previsioni.

this is a snippet of my python code

```
json_array = [];

for path in files:
    with open(path, 'r') as fr:
        print "Parsing xmldoc %s" % path

        xmldoc = minidom.parse(fr)

        if tipo == "allerte":
            items = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("point")
        else:
            items = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("localita")

        for item in items:
            obj = dict()

            if tipo == "allerte":
                obj['id'] = item.getElementsByTagName("idpoint")[0].firstChild.nodeValue



            else:
                obj['id'] = item.getElementsByTagName("idpoint")[0].firstChild.nodeValue

            obj['latitude'] = float(item.getElementsByTagName("latitude")[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
            obj['longitude'] = float(item.getElementsByTagName("longitude")[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
            #TODO: IL symbol code va recuperato dalla prima previsione
            sobj['symbolcode'] = int(item.getElementsByTagName("id_tempo")[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
            json_array.append(obj)

return json.dumps(json_array)
```

Any help to integrate this code for create into json file 2 element for the 2 tag relation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick way to get json from xml, using [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict). This module creates nice dict from your xml, and you can easily  manipulate your data like it is pure json.

Let's assume, that your xml sample is saved as `t2.xml` file, enveloped by `<xml>...</xml>` tags.

Then this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import sys
import xmltodict
import json

with open('t2.xml', 'r') as data:
    print "Parsing xmldoc test.xml"

    dict = xmltodict.parse(data)

    print(json.dumps(dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

will produce json as following:

```
{
    "xml": {
        "idpoint": "1021", 
        "latitude": "45.188377380", 
        "longitude": "8.612257004", 
        "previsione": [
            {
                "@time": "2015-07-11T12:00:00", 
                "desc_tempo": "sereno", 
                "id_tempo": "1", 
                "symbol_day": "1", 
                "temp": "33"
            }, 
            {
                "@time": "2015-07-11T18:00:00", 
                "desc_tempo": "sereno", 
                "id_tempo": "1", 
                "symbol_day": "1", 
                "temp": "29"
            }
        ], 
        "tipopoint": "1"
    }
}
```

In particular, you get both of your `previsione` elements properly in an array and can use them as you need.